# moving a C code from visual studio to linux

Tags: c, gcc

hello i am trying to sort a linked list 
when i sort it it works on visual studio but when i move it to linux the linked list does not get sorted for some reason.
my sorts gets a pointer to a pointer of the list and this is my sort code:
i call the function like this:
`SortQueue(&pprocessQueue, ProcessPrIdCompare);`
and here is my function
the function uses EnqueueInOrder which puts every link in his place.

```
 void SortQueue(Queue **pqueue, CompareFunction CompareElements)
 {
   Queue *ptemp = CreateQueue( (*pqueue)->CopyElement, 
                               (*pqueue)->FreeElement,
                               CompareElements,
                               (*pqueue)->PrintElement );

   (*pqueue)->CompareElements = CompareElements;

   while (!(IsEmpty(*pqueue) == SUCCESS))
     EnqueueInOrder(ptemp, DequeueLink(*pqueue));

   while (!(IsEmpty(ptemp) == SUCCESS))
    EnqueueInOrder(*pqueue, DequeueLink(ptemp));

   FreeQueue(ptemp);
}
```

1 more thing i am using gcc to compile.

Comment: Could you please format the code using the '101010' button.  Beat me too it!

Comment: I think the problem is in a part of the code you did not paste here.

Comment: Does your code compile with no warnings: use -ansi -pedantic -W -Wall -Werror

Comment: yea it does compile without any errors but doesnt sort anything in linux (in visual studio it works perfectly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the problem with your code.  It'll probably be wise to check the code that reposes outside of the code you've shown us.

Comment: i found out what my problem was ... i didnt use casting on the compare function defenition thx anyway